With Nesbot Carbon diffForHumans(), display 19 months instead of 1 year when less than 26 months
I display a diffForHumans with one part
echo Carbon::create('1 hour 59 minutes ago')->diffForHumans(); // 1 hour ago
echo Carbon::create('1 day 23 hours ago')->diffForHumans(); // 1 day ago
echo Carbon::create('1 month 23 days ago')->diffForHumans(); // 1 month ago
echo Carbon::create('1 year 10 months ago')->diffForHumans(); // 1 year ago

For up to 25 months, I'd prefer to see months before it switches to year: e.g. to see 23 months instead of 1 year.
More generaly, I would like to keep the lower unit (like month) when the higher unit (like year) is 1 or 2.
I would also like the display to be as compact as possible.
How do I do that?

This is an update to skip weeks
function diffForHumans(Carbon $carbon)
{
   return $carbon->diffForHumans([
        'syntax' => CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE, // no ago 
        'short' => true, // e.g. m instead of minutes
        'skip' => $carbon->diffInMinutes() < 3 * 60 ? ['hour'] : (
            $carbon->diffInHours() < 3 * 24 ? ['day'] : (
                // $carbon->diffInDays() < 3 * 7 ? ['week'] : (
                    $carbon->diffInWeeks() < 3 * 4 ? ['month','week'] : (
                        $carbon->diffInMonths() < 3 * 12 ? ['year'] :
                            []
                    ))),
    ]);
}

Test output (same input data):
| solution | default carbon | input |
| 119min    | 1 uur geleden | 1 hour 59 minutes ago |
| 47u   | 1 dag geleden | 1 day 23 hours ago |
| 54d   | 1 maand geleden   | 1 month 23 days ago |
| 22mnd | 1 jaar geleden    | 1 year 10 months ago |
| 2min  | 2 minuten geleden | 2 minutes ago |
| 3min  | 3 minuten geleden | 3 minutes ago |
| 120min    | 2 uur geleden | 2 hours ago |
| 3u    | 3 uur geleden | 3 hours ago |
| 48u   | 2 dagen geleden   | 2 days ago |
| 3d    | 3 dagen geleden   | 3 days ago |
| 14d   | 2 weken geleden   | 2 weeks ago |
| 21d   | 3 weken geleden   | 3 weeks ago |
| 62d   | 2 maanden geleden | 2 months ago |
| 3mnd  | 3 maanden geleden | 3 months ago |
| 104w  | 2 jaar geleden    | 2 years ago |
| 3j    | 3 jaar geleden    | 3 years ago |


use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonInterface;

function diffForHumans(Carbon $carbon)
{
   return $carbon->diffForHumans([
        'syntax' => CarbonInterface::DIFF_ABSOLUTE, // no ago 
        'short' => true, // e.g. m instead of minutes
        'skip' => $carbon->diffInMinutes() < 3 * 60 ? ['hour'] : (
            $carbon->diffInHours() < 3 * 24 ? ['day'] : (
                $carbon->diffInDays() < 3 * 7 ? ['week'] : (
                    $carbon->diffInWeeks() < 3 * 4 ? ['month'] : (
                        $carbon->diffInMonths() < 3 * 12 ? ['year'] :
                            []
                    )))),
    ]);
}

Test:
function test($carbonString)
{
    return diffForHumans(
        $c = Carbon::create($carbonString)) . "\t" .  
        $c->diffForHumans() ."\t". 
        $carbonString . "\n";
}

echo '<pre>';

echo test('1 hour 59 minutes ago');
echo test('1 day 23 hours ago');
echo test('1 month 23 days ago');
echo test('1 year 10 months ago');

echo test('2 minutes ago');
echo test('3 minutes ago');
echo test('2 hours ago');
echo test('3 hours ago');
echo test('2 days ago');
echo test('3 days ago');
echo test('2 weeks ago');
echo test('3 weeks ago');
echo test('2 months ago');
echo test('3 months ago');
echo test('2 years ago');
echo test('3 years ago');

The test output is:
| solution | default carbon | input
| 119m     | 1 hour ago     | 1 hour 59 minutes ago
| 47h      | 1 day ago      | 1 day 23 hours ago
| 7w       | 1 month ago    | 1 month 23 days ago
| 22mos    | 1 year ago     | 1 year 10 months ago
| 2m       | 2 minutes ago  | 2 minutes ago
| 3m       | 3 minutes ago  | 3 minutes ago
| 120m     | 2 hours ago    | 2 hours ago
| 3h       | 3 hours ago    | 3 hours ago
| 48h      | 2 days ago     | 2 days ago
| 3d       | 3 days ago     | 3 days ago
| 14d      | 2 weeks ago    | 2 weeks ago
| 3w       | 3 weeks ago    | 3 weeks ago
| 8w       | 2 months ago   | 2 months ago
| 3mos     | 3 months ago   | 3 months ago
| 104w     | 2 years ago    | 2 years ago
| 3yrs     | 3 years ago    | 3 years ago

